# Tab control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I created a new WPF application with a TextBox, ListBox, RichTextBox and a Menu. I want to create a tab circle between first 3 controls. When RichTextBox is focused and user presses Tab (KeyDown event), I set focus to my TextBox. But when I run program and press Tab, Menu is focused instead of TextBox.

I tried with a new C# application but didn't get this error. Somehow this only happens in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `TabIndex` on every control. That would allow you to make your own order of fields.

If you want to exclude your menu from the tab stops, use this on it:

```
KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
```

Note: there is no need to handle the events yourself. WPF will handle the Tab key.